# Programmatically Gravity set of TextView in android not working

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am trying set gravity of text view "v" but its not working . basically in this code a drawable bitmap created through text view...

```
private Drawable[] getDrawableFromData(String[] data) {
    Drawable[] ret = new Drawable[data.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        TextView v = new TextView(this);

        v.setText(data[i]);
        v.setTypeface(TypeFaces.get(getApplicationContext(),
                Constants.TYPE_FACE_PATH));

        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        v.setTextSize(60);
        v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
             v.setTextColor(Utils.getHexColor(SplashScreenData.getInstance().object.themeOptions.circular   Wheel.TextColor));

        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        v.layout(0, 0, 150, v.getMeasuredHeight() + 15);
        //v.setLayoutParams(Gravity.CENTER);
        v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        v.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
        ret[i] = d;
    }
    return ret;
}
```